# How I have pass parameters to function in kohana frame work

Tags: php, kohana

I have following lines of code in bootstap.php for route,

```
Route::set('ads','ad/<ad>(/<affiliate>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'ads',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Then how I've to pass parameters to that function.Url is localhost/index.php/ads/ is working but when i'm giving localhost/index.php/ads/12 it show 404 error.I know how to access those values in ads.php but how i've to pass the parameters from url.

Comment: Please note [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#signatures)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it wasn't your typo (`ads` not `ad`) but with this route:

```
Route::set('ads','ads/<ad>(/<affiliate>)')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'ads',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

localhost/index.php/ads/12 has to work. In your controller you can access the parameters by:

```
$this->request->param('ad');
```

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
Route::set('ads','ad/<ad>(/<affiliate>)', array('affiliate' => '.*'))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'ads',
    'action'     => 'index',
));
```

Comment: it is optional parameters,if i pass then it read that value otherwise default will be null